# Akka Remote: get autogenerated port

Tags: akka, akka-remote-actor

I have a Java client, which obtains an autogenerated port. After starting the actor system, I want to access the port.

```
Config clientConfig = ConfigFactory.parseString("akka.remote.netty.tcp.port = 0")
        .withFallback(ConfigFactory.parseString("akka.remote.netty.tcp.hostname = " + serverHostName))
        .withFallback(ConfigFactory.load("common"));

actorSystem = ActorSystem.create("clientActorSystem", clientConfig);

// how to access the generated port here..!?
```

The port must already be set since the log output after `ActorSystem.create(...)` is like that:

```
[INFO] [03/31/2016 14:11:32.042] [main] [akka.remote.Remoting] Starting remoting
[INFO] [03/31/2016 14:11:32.233] [main] [akka.remote.Remoting] Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://actorSystem@localhost:58735]
[INFO] [03/31/2016 14:11:32.234] [main] [akka.remote.Remoting] Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://actorSystem@localhost:58735]
```

If I try to get it via the configuration with `actorSystem.settings().config().getValue("akka.remote.netty.tcp.port")`, I still get 0 as defined before.

Has anyone an idea how this port (58735 in the example) can be accessed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using scala you can get Option of port on which Actor system is currently running:

```
val port = system.provider.getDefaultAddress.port
```

Hope you will be able to get the same code in Java.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer probably worked for older versions of Akka but as of now (version 2.5.x) you will be getting something like:

> Error:(22, 18) method provider in trait ActorRefFactory cannot be accessed in akka.actor.ActorSystem

The solution would be to use [akka extensions](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/extending-akka.html?language=scala). Here is how I use it:

#### Example. scala

```
package example

import akka.actor._

class AddressExtension(system: ExtendedActorSystem) extends Extension {
  val address: Address = system.provider.getDefaultAddress
}

object AddressExtension extends ExtensionId[AddressExtension] {
  def createExtension(system: ExtendedActorSystem): AddressExtension = new AddressExtension(system)

  def hostOf(system: ActorSystem): String = AddressExtension(system).address.host.getOrElse("")
  def portOf(system: ActorSystem): Int    = AddressExtension(system).address.port.getOrElse(0)
}

object Main extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem("Main")
  println(AddressExtension.portOf(system))
}
```